# Can't access class public property

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have created a class called Building which has a bunch of different types of rooms, though for now i only have one. I am trying to now access a property in a room type class but for some reason it does not give me access to it.

This is my class:

```
public abstract class Building {

    public RoomType roomType { get; private set; }
    public RoomManager roomManager {get; private set;}
    public int x {get; private set;}
    public int y {get; private set;}

    public Building(int x, int y, RoomManager rm, RoomType rT){
        SetPosition(x,y);
        roomManager = rm;
        roomType    = rT;
    }
    void SetPosition(int tx, int ty){
        x = tx;
        y = ty;
    }
}

public class KitchenRoom : Building {
        public Kitchen reference {get; private set;}

        public KitchenRoom(int x, int y, RoomManager rM, Kitchen kitchen) : base(x,y,rM,RoomType.Kitchen){
            reference   = elevator;
        }
}
```

So i create a new KitchenRoom like so:

```
//Buildings = List<Building>();
//I use type Building because there will be more than just KitchenRoom in this list eventually.

buildings.Add(new KitchenRoom(x,y,go.getComponent<RoomManager>(),go.GetComponent<Kitchen>()));
```

So now i want to access the value `reference` so i did this:

```
for(int i=0;i<buildings.Count; i++){
    if(buildings[i] is KitchenRoom){
       buildings[i].reference.someMethod(); // access to reference non existant
    }
}
```

So i don't seem to have access to `reference`. But i don't know what i got wrong here.

Secondary minor question:

I was told, that run time type checks aka using `is KitchenRoom` is not a good idea? But i don't know how else to do it, is there any truth to this, are the better implementations to this?

Comment: There is no class called Room in your code.....

Comment: Sorry i meant building not Room :) edited.

Comment: Ok. Juust realized you are still editing it

Comment: Yes its all updated correctly now.

Comment: Where is `buildings` declared? You used `buildings[i]`  but buildings is not declared anywhere.

Comment: It's declared in a class else where, didn't want to put all the code in so i put a comment stating what the type buildings was aka List<Building>()

Comment: It's declared, but in comment :D `//Buildings = List<Building>();`

Comment: It's not actually `declared` but it explains it's type there to remind myself :P but trust me its declared :P I'd have a syntax error if it wasn't.

Comment: @mihkov I saw that but `//Buildings = List<Building>();` != `//buildings= List<Building>();`

Comment: It's because your List is of type "Building". Cast each element to a "KitchenRoom" and then try accessing. ((KitchenRoom)buildings[i]).reference.someMethod()

Comment: Isn't casting usually able to be avoided if there is inheritance? @VenkatatAxiomStudios

Comment: Not in cases like this. What you're thinking about is cases where the property/field is accessible in the base class. Here though, it's your inherited class.

Comment: @VenkatatAxiomStudios Ah okay, also what about checking the building[i] type? I was told using `is` for run time type checks was also a bad way to go about it ?

Comment: I'm just going to write an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to access a property in your child class without casting it first.

The property `reference` only exists in your class `KitchenRoom`, but does not exist in `Building`

To access the `reference` property of `KitchemRoom`, you should [cast](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx) the element to `KitchenRoom`

Code example

```
for(int i=0;i<buildings.Count; i++){
    if(buildings[i] is KitchenRoom){
       ((KitchenRoom)buildings[i]).reference.someMethod(); // Cast to KitchenRoom first, then access
    }
}
```

Not directly related to question, but more to continue what's going on in the comments.

The [is](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/scekt9xw.aspx) keyword is used to check whether an Object is of a specific type. It does NOT perform any sort of casting, but rather is meant to used to check whether a cast can be performed without throwing errors.

Code example

```
public class Garden : NotBuilding {
    //A class that does not inherit from Building
}


var aBuilding = new Building(); //An object of type building
var aKitchenRoom = new KitchenRoom(); //An object of type KitchenRoom, which inherits from Building in your code


Debug.Log(aBuilding is Building); //true
Debug.Log(aKitchenRoom is Building); //true
Debug.Log(aKitchenRoom is Garden); //false
Debug.Log(aKitchenRoom is NotBuilding); //false
```

The [as](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) keyword is another way of casting, with the added advantage of not throwing an [InvalidCastException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidcastexception(v=vs.110).aspx) if a cast fails.

Code example

Another way of writing your code above

```
for(int i=0;i<buildings.Count; i++){
    var kitchenRoom = buildings[i] as KitchenRoom; //Cast to a KitchenRoom. Method returns null if it fails
    if(kitchenRoom != null)
        kitchenRoom.reference.someMethod();
}
```